# Is Platform::String really so useless?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to write a few lines of code in C++/CX in a "Windows Store" (aka Metro Style) application, and I am surprised to see that [Platform::String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755812.aspx) is missing many basic string operations like ["replace"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) or ["index of"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I suppose I could use the internal data, pass it to a std:string instance and apply the operations I need, but I would like to know if I am missing some "Platform::* only" way of doing these operations.

*Please note this question is about C++/CX, not C#.*

Comment: SO is a question site, not a bug tracker, so the title should be a question, not a complaint ;-)

Comment: [String::Begin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825849.aspx), [String::End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825864.aspx), What more do you need?

Comment: The string has iterators, can't you simply use standard algorithms?

Comment: Platform::String is immutable, so mutating operations like "replace" make no sense. Non-mutating operations can be done just fine by using iterators in the standard algorithms. It doesn't look useless at all to me.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes that makes more sense! thanks!

Comment: @yms Hmm, I may have been misled by the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755812.aspx to believe that the strings are immutable. However, the Begin method returns a non-const pointer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825849.aspx. It seems you can mutate individual elements of the string but not add or remove any. Weird.

Comment: Nevermind that, seems like it's a documentation bug (https://twitter.com/JamesMcNellis/status/249183128097259522). It is really immutable.

Comment: @MarkRansom: What would you propose instead? Or, more to the point, how would you have solved the problem that `Platform::String` solves? (Note: You cannot use a time machine as part of your solution.)

Comment: @IInspectable what problem does it solve that `std::string` doesn't?

Comment: @MarkRansom: A standardized ABI, for starters. And being projectable into a language that doesn't support inheritance, like JavaScript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Windows Runtime string type, [`HSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205775.aspx) is immutable and is reference counted.

The `Platform::String` type in C++/CX is simply a wrapper around the `HSTRING` type and the handful of operations that it supports (see the functions that start with `Windows` in the [Windows Runtime C++ Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205774.aspx) list).

There are no operations that mutate the string because the string type is immutable (hence why there is no `Replace`).  There are a few non-mutating operations (certainly fewer than C++'s `std::wstring`).

`Platform::String` does provide `Begin()` and `End()` member functions (and non-member `begin()` and `end()` overloads) that return random access iterators into the string (they return pointers, `wchar_t const*`, and pointers are valid random access iterators).  You can use these iterators with any of the C++ Standard Library algorithms that take random access iterators and do not attempt to mutate the underlying sequence.  For example, consider using `std::find` to find the index of the first occurrence of a character.

If you need to mutate a string, use `std::wstring` or `std::vector<wchar_t>`.  Ideally, consider using the C++ `std::wstring` as much as possible in your program and only use the C++/CX `Platform::String` where you need to interoperate with other Windows Runtime components (i.e., across the ABI boundary).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this answer. Would you mind taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581714/why-my-c-cx-unit-test-does-not-fail)? It feels like a found a bug in the c++ test framework...

Comment: @yms:  That is a good question; I'm not sure of the answer, but I can try to find someone who can answer it.  For what it's worth, I've found it useful for unit testing purposes to synchronize all asynchronous operations (using a spin wait, to circumvent the STA-blocking restrictions).  It's simple and straightforward to do this; you can see a generic example in [my CxxReflect project's unit test code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533883/platformstring-is-kind-of-useless/12534823#comment16958615_12534823).

Answer (score 11):

That is because it isn't intended to be a std::string replacement. From the docs:

> The Platform::String Class provides methods for several common string operations, but it's not designed to be a full-featured string class. In your C++ module, use standard C++ string types such as wstring for any significant text processing, and then convert the final result to Platform::String^ before you pass it to or from a public interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699879.aspx

So the bottom line is: use `std::wstring` like you were used to in C++ and only convert to `Platform::String` when needed.

I think that it is probably better that way, because `Platform::String` has some pretty confusing semantics (for example `nullptr` and the empty string are the same thing, so `ref new String() == nullptr` is true).

Comment: `Platform::String` has odd semantics, yes, especially with respect to "null."  The oddities are largely caused by the fact that the Windows Runtime string type, `HSTRING`, is a value type (and thus has no "null" value) but the type _is_ reference counted and requires explicit creation and destruction.  It is, in a sense, a bit of a mix between a value type and a reference type.