# platform::string Functions in Windows 8/RT C++

Tags: c++, string, winapi, visual-c++, c++-cx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Platform::String is kind of useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533883/platformstring-is-kind-of-useless)

I'm new to Windows development and the new Visual C++ APIs are driving me nuts. I've most recently run into a seeming lack of string functions. Are there basic functions available such as:

- substring
- strpos or similar
- regular expressions

My ultimate goal is to take a file path such as "C:\foo\bar\baz.jpg" and extract the deepest directory. In this example, I'm looking for "bar".

Perhaps of a greater concern, I've found that it's incredibly difficult to find current documentation for Win 8 APIs. What's the best place to look for questions like this?

Comment: I retagged your question, removing the "wpf" tag and adding the "c++-cx" tag (since `Platform::String` is a C++/CX class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinRT C++/CX classes like `Platform::String` should be used only **at the boundary** of your apps/components. *Inside* your apps/components you should just use ordinary ISO C++ classes.

So you can just use `std::wstring` (since `Platform::String` is Unicode) with its methods and Boost's helpers, and then convert from/to `std::wstring` to/from `Platform::String` at the boundary.

Comment: Aha! This was my biggest confusion. Thanks a ton for helping me clear it up.

Comment: For others wondering how to do what Mr.C64 suggests, this site has a lot of great info: [Platform::String, std::wstring, and Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438486(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

substring is part of the standard C++ library.

```
string x = "abc";
string y = x.substr(1, 2);
```

Not completely sure I know what strpos does, but assuming it's about finding the position of a character in a string or similar then it's also standard.

```
string x = "abc";
string::size_type p = x.find('b');
```

Regexes can be found in the cross platform boost library, http://boost.org.

Comment: Regexes are also part of C++11

Comment: I need a property on a class that is bindable, so I've been using platform::string. Should I use standard C++ strings until I have what I need and then create a platform::string afterwards? Or am I misunderstanding some other aspect here?

Comment: And to find the _last_ occurrence of a string/character, there is [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).

Comment: C++/CX's `Platform::String` uses _Unicode_, so - at least in MS Visual C++ - you should use `std::wstring` as corresponding C++ class (not `std::string`).